# Migrate SQL Server to Windows from Linux

Tags: sql-server

I've been running SQL Server Express 2019 on our Linux Server, and I am currently planning our disaster recovery setup.

I was already able to backup the database automatically, but I can't seem to restore the database to a SQL Server on Windows. I've been using a `localDB` instance to test it, but I seem to be unable to restore the database to it

**Note**: the `.bak` file came from Linux SQL Server.

Every time I try to restore the database it says that the sysfiles1 is corrupted, but when I try to restore a database from a Windows SQL Server, it works fine. I also tried to restore the Linux database back to itself and that works, too.

There have been many articles that show how to migrate from Windows to Linux but I can't find any that shows how to migrate from Linux to Windows.

The reason I want to test if I can go back to Windows is that we only have one server that runs Linux in the office and a lot of Windows computers.

TLDR: I want to know if its possible to migrate database from Linux to Windows

Comment: `I've been using localDB instance to test` why? That's an embedded database engine, nothing like the full server you want to restore. You won't be using LocalDb for recovery either.  Backups work. Install either SQL Server Express or SQL Server Developer edition and restore the backups there

Comment: Post the actual commands you used to restore the backups and the actual, full error message

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos off topic but would Docker be a good solution here? I know it can be used on the newer versions of Windows server - I guess an instance of the Express image could be used and then deployed to the target windows server?

Comment: As [this duplicate question at dba.stackexchange.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68084138/migrate-mssql-server-to-windows-from-linux) shows, there's nothing special. It's far more likely that the backup *is* corrupt, or that the server versions don't match.

Comment: Although the formats ought to be fully compatible (with a specific error about the file version if not), it's possible some incompatibility has snuck in; see if the `@@VERSION`s of the DB engines match and compare with [known builds](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2019x). Normally the Windows one can be slightly behind because the Linux/Azure images get some cutting edge changes.

Comment: @Umar.H how would that help in disaster recovery? If the server hardware fails, you only have the backups

Comment: I don't really, if I am honest, see the point in running SQL Server in a container on Windows (be it a Linux or Windows one) @Umar.H either, apart from as a learning experience. The Windows Version of SQL Server has more functionality than its Linux counter part (the latter is still a "work in progress" for some tools). Though, as a daily Linux Driver, I will admit I run all my SQL instances in Containers (though LXD not Docker).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah, I thought there was a mismatch between the technologies on different OS's causing the conflicts. My reasoning is more to do with migrations.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Its actually my fist time to use the localdb instance and thought that it would just be a lightweight counter part of the Express edition. I'll try to install the express first. just really wanted to the using the local db and thought that it works the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is LocalDB. I got same error each time I tried to restore database from linux. Then I made same restore in another server (SQL Server Standart is installed) and it successfully restored database. Then I restored to my local machine from that SQL Server Standart backup.